# Что будет возвращать функция?

Tags: java

Выполняю пример кода в котором переопределен метод `equals()`,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    Money money = (Money) object;
    return amount == money.amount && getClass().equals(money.getClass());
}
```

Вот несколько вопросов:

1. Как мы можем прикастить `object` к `Money` так явно, если переданный `object`, не обязательно будет `Money`, тут явно может быть ошибка насколько я понимаю.
2. Насчет `return` насколько я понимаю вернется `true` или `false` если `amount` равен или не равен  `money.amount && getClass().equals(money.getClass())`, но что считает эта строчка?  `money.amount` - понятно, но как в этом условии используется оператор `&&` и что возвращает `getClass()` не понятно, я читал документацию но все равно не понял. Объясните пожалуйста по-русски))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Так и можем, компилятор не будет возражать. Если `object` нельзя будет привести к `Money`, в ходе работы программы будет выброшено исключение `ClassCastException`. Но поскольку совсем произвольные объекты на равенство сравниваются нечасто (коллекции типизированы, наши собственные методы возвращают известно что), то может прокатить.
2. [Приоритет оператора](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) `==` выше, чем у `&&`, поэтому сначала проверяются на равенство `amount`. Если `amount` содержит разные значение (для примитивных типов), или ссылаются на разные экземпляры объекта, выражение возвращает `false` (оператор `&&` работает по короткой схеме, и если левый операнд - `false`, то правый не оценивается). Если `amount` равны, то проверяется эквивалентность классов объектов `this` и `object`.

Вообще, это код из книги Kent Beck [Test-driven Development: By Example](https://books.google.ru/books?id=CUlsAQAAQBAJ) из одного из промежуточных этапов разработки, поэтому он не является сам по себе примером правильного кода, и скорее иллюстрирует принцип TDD "сделайте минимум работы, чтобы пройти тесты". Проверка на равенство классов нужна там, чтобы убедиться, что деньги представлены в одной валюте.

---

Каждый объект относится к какому-то классу (типу), который никогда не меняется. `Object.getClass()` возвращает этот класс. Класс может входить в иерархию (у него есть предки и потомки). Когда мы выполняем приведение к типу `T`, мы говорим компилятору, что хотим рассматривать объект по ссылке, как объект типа `T` и обращаться к членам класса, определенным в `T` или его предках.

На этом этапе в книге создано два вида валюты: доллары и франки, представленные классами `Dollar` и `Franc`. Оба класса являются наследниками класса `Money`, содержащего поле `amount` и метод `equals`.

После приведения параметра `object` к типу `Money` мы можем обращаться к `Money.amount`, но этого недостаточно, т.к. 5 долларов оказываются равны 5 франкам. Поэтому для равенства дополнительно проверяется равенство классов самих объектов.

Comment: Да верно я сейчас читаю эту книгу. Но как понять этот кусок кода `getClass().equals(money.getClass())`? первое `getClass()` вернет класс в котором находится метод(в нашем случае Money и будет сравнивать его с money.getClass() (что логично вернет тоже Money) тогда смысл проверки? если заведомо понятно что с обеих сторон будет Money. Или я не так понимаю?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko `money.getClass()` не обязательно будет `Money.class`. Это может быть его потомок. Приведение типов пройдёт, но это *точное* сравнение - нет.

Answer (score 4):

1) Да. Тут может быть ошибка. Если `object` не `Money` и не его потомок, то преобразование типа не удастся и мы получим исключение.

2) Выражение в `return` эквивалентно следующему:

```
(this.amount == money.amount) && this.getClass().equals(money.getClass());
```

То есть оно проверяет у двух объектов совпадение членов `amount` и совпадение (точное, без учёта наследования) их классов. Метод `Object.getClass` как раз и возвращает фактический класс объекта, для которого он был вызван.

---

Конечно, код плохой. Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
class Money {
    // ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object object) {
        if (object == null) 
            return false;
        if (object == this)
            return true;
        if (! getClass().equals(money.getClass()))
          return false;

        return amount == ((Money) object).amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)если я правильно понимаю то вторая проверка проверяет на то является ли переданный обьект обьектом this(в данном случае Money), то вернет true, но не проверит на совпадает ли amount. Почему? 2)Все 3 проверки исключают все возможные варианты, тогда метод просто не добежит до последних двух строчек... Он проверит обьект нал не нал, потом проверит 2 возможных варианта Money или нет 3- го не дано. При каком сценарии он добежит до последних 2-х строк?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Вы путаете *класс* и *экземпляр класса*. Второе сравнение проверяет не классы, а переменные (экземпляры) этого класса. То есть, например, это сравнение даст `true` для `a.equals(a)` и `false` для `b.equals(a)`.

Comment: @kff а смысл сначала использовать `instanceof`, а затем делать проверку на точное соответствие классов? Достаточно что-то одно проверить

Comment: @PavelParshin А! Точно! Это я из проверки с допустимым наследованием выдернул... А тут же требуется точное совпадение...